# Querying to exclude empty values, yet I am getting those

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to aggregate NON-empty fields.

I am aggregating from my posts collection, and I am trying to aggregate so that I get posts `$sample` were the value for the field `content` is NOT empty using `$match` and `$ne`. However, I am still getting empty values. Not sure of exactly why.

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {$sample:{"size": 50 }},
    {$match: {"content": { $ne: "" }}},
    {$group: {"_id" : "$_id", "post" : { "$push" : "$$ROOT" }}},
    {$unwind : "$post" }
])
```

I am expecting to have NON-empty values. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `{$match: {"content": { $ne:null }}},`?

Comment: @abdul, I've tried that too. But in the database the `content` field sometimes appears **blank**, meaning it doesn't say: _null_.

Comment: what do you mean blank.  Like it doesn't exist or just empty string?

Comment: @abdul, yes **empty string**. That's why I am checking `$ne : ""`.

Comment: In that case i don't see any problem in your query. May be if you can post a sample from your db.

Comment: my last suggestion would to check if the field exists first.  Like `"content" : {"$exists" : true, "$nin" : [null, ""]}`

Comment: @abdul, please share that as an answer with more details, so that I can mark your answer as the answer. Thanks a lot for this suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$nin` to filter out documents with an empty string or `null` value for a specific field. Something like this.

```
"content" : {"$nin" : [null, ""]}
```

Comment: Although this isn't the direct solution, that `$nin` query operator is nice compared to the one I used. BTW, it is enough with `$nin` no need to use `$exists`.

Comment: @John, yeah. In this case  `$nin` filters out the documents in which the content is null or empty string.

Comment: @John  Modified my answer based on your comment.

Comment: May I also add: `{"$nin" : [null, "", {}]}`